# MySQL cache result?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such procedure in MySQL database. It works strange. As you see procedure has 2 input parameters which can be always different. Thus, the results should also be different. But it seems like MySQL caches variables or something else. When I run procedure with different input values, I see always the same data. Is it possible to enable cache only for current procedure? I am really confused and need advice.

```
PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
  IN START_DATE VARCHAR(19),
  IN END_DATE VARCHAR(19)
)
BEGIN
  SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=18446744073709551615;

  SET @START_DATE := START_DATE ;
  SET @END_DATE:= END_DATE;

  SET @IDS_TABLE_1 = (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(POSITION_ID)
    FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE
      DATE_TIME BETWEEN  @START_DATE AND @END_DATE
  );

  SET @SELECT = CONCAT("
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_2
    WHERE
      C.ID_OBJECT NOT IN  (@IDS_TABLE_1)
  ")

   PREPARE FINAL_SELECT FROM @SELECT;
   EXECUTE FINAL_SELECT;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE FINAL_SELECT;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you be using dynamic SQL for this?  Just do:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM TABLE_2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM TABLE_1 t1
                  WHERE t1.DATE_TIME BETWEEN @START_DATE AND @END_DATE AND
                        t2.ID_OBJECT = t1.POSITION_ID
                 );
```

With an index on `TABLE_1(POSITION_ID, DATE_TIME)`, this should also have good performance.